# What are the factors on which wavelength of X-rays depends upon?

Tags: wavelength, photoelectric-effect, x-rays

So the thing is that I was learning about X-rays and I came across this line that minimum wavelength of continuous X-ray spectra depends only upon Anode voltage about which I'm sceptical because

$$eV=h\nu_{\text{max}},$$

so the minimum wavelength should or maximum frequency should depend upon accelerating potential which is the potential difference between anode and cathode but someone said me that it is only anodic potential upon which the minimum wavelength or maximum frequency depends upon.So that is my doubt.

Comment: Wavelength and frequency of light are directly related through $c$. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Well $c =\nu \cdot \lambda$ solves your problem I guess.

Comment: What I'm skeptically about is the fact that I came across a statement that it depends only upon anodic voltage.See Cathode will be at -ve potential,anode at +ve and we have accelerated a charged particle.So What my problem is that instead of potential difference,it said only anodic voltage about which I'm skeptical.I've even stated this that I came across this line that minimum wavelength and so maximum frequency depends only upon Anodic Voltage but it should be the potential difference between anode and cathode shouldn't it??This is what I'm skeptical about.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite get your question.

Yes eV = hv(max)
or it can be EV = hc\lamba(min wavelength)

So what're you skeptical about??

Comment: What I'm skeptically about is the fact that I came across a statement that it depends only upon anodic voltage.See Cathode will be at -ve potential,anode at +ve and we have accelerated a charged particle.So What my problem is that instead of potential difference,it said only anodic voltage about which I'm skeptical.

Comment: You're right, it must be the potential difference and not just anodic potential.

Answer (score 1):

Wavelength depends inversely on energy or stopping potential
While frequency is directly proportional